# Java Validation - Adding @Valid constraint to custom constraint throws "@Valid is not applicable to annotation type"

Tags: java, validation, annotations, bean-validation

I have a model object annotated with Java validation annotations.

```
class Criteria{
    @NotEmpty String id;    
    @NotEmpty String name;
    String fileName;
    String hours;   
}
```

As per the business requirement, either fileName or hours field will be populated, to validate which I have a custom validator 'CriteriaValidator' written.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CriteriaValidator.class})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE , ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface ValidCriteria {
    String message() default "{Criteria.Invalid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The model above is passed in as input parameter for a method which is also annotated with @Valid and @ValidCriteria.

```
public void update(@Valid @ValidCriteria Criteria criteria){...}
```

The issue I have is with 2 annotations in the method. I have to add @Valid in order to check constraints annotated within the class. My custom validator checks only for the existence of one of the 2 fields: filename or hours.

The question I have is, how do I have a single annotation @ValidCriteria which validates my special requirement as well as the @NotEmpty fields in the object.

I tried adding @Valid in my custom constraint @ValidCriteria, however I get the error '@Valid is not applicable to annotation type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ValidCriteria` annotation should be on the Criteria class:

```
@ValidCriteria
class Criteria{
    @NotEmpty String id;    
    @NotEmpty String name;
    String fileName;
    String hours;   
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It works perfectly and my method signature only has @Valid constraint now.

Comment: Sorry, but if I want to validate class to which I dont have access and cannot annotate with validation annotation? I created custom annotation and want use it to validate external class in controller method parameter.